# regex for non alphabets or nothing

Tags: python, regex

I want to identify "how" from python strings.

```
string1
how to find
it is a show
okay how to
```

Used:

```
df[df['string1'].str.contains("how",case=False)]
```

Output coming:

```
string1
how to find
it is a show
okay how to
```

As 'show' contains 'how'

output needed:

```
string1
how to find
okay how to
```

after that i used

```
df[df['string1'].str.contains(r"\Whow",case=False)]
```

but output i got is:

```
string1
okay how to
```

which is again worng.

 regex '\W' is not including nothing. 
 how to achieve this?

Comment: `df['string1'].str.contains(" how ",case=False)`

Comment: @kaleidawave then there should be a space before how. Which i dont want

Comment: it should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60712160/1138192

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need boundaries (`\b`) for the pattern, otherwise it will also match substrings contained in words:

```
df[df['string1'].str.contains(r"\bhow\b",case=False)]

      string1
1    how to find
3    okay how to
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it as word boundary using `\b` using regex https://regex101.com/r/2Dlnxj/1

```
df['string1'].str.contains("\bhow\b",case=False)
```