# Use str.contains only with WHOLE WORDS using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

Consider:

```
array = ['... ,  '...'  , '.... ' ,....]
results = df[df['Message'].str.contains('|'.join(array)).fillna(False)]
```

How can we force the `str.contains` to use only WHOLE WORDS from array ?

Comment: have a look at [python-pandas-series-str-contains-whole-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359601/python-pandas-series-str-contains-whole-word/39359789)

Comment: @AnuragDabas: Yeah ,tried this `pattern = '\b' + '|'.join(array) + '\b'
results = df[df['Message'].str.contains(pattern).fillna(False)]` , but is doesn't work.

Comment: Try escaping the `\b` and also wrap strings with () like this: 
`pattern = '\\b(' + '|'.join(arr) + ')\\b'`.  `match` works better instead of `contains` since now it produces a warning.

Comment: @Emma: Make it as an answer and I'll choose it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need wrapping all words (w1|w2|w3) to match against any words in the array. Then add a word boundary, `\b`, in both side with an escape.

```
pattern = '\\b(' + '|'.join(arr) + ')\\b'
df[df['Message'].str.contains(pattern).fillna(False)]
```

Now since I added the extract group `()`, contains will produce a warning.

```
UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
```

To handle this warning, change `contains` to `match`.

```
df[df['Message'].str.match(pattern).fillna(False)]
```

Comment: ``str.contains`` produced the expected results for me, whereas ``str.match`` failed to find anything.. all search from ``str.match`` came back as empty