# filter a DataFrame using complete word only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a large DataFrame (named: complete) of data (only two columns). I want to filter it using complete words only, instead of substrings. Ex:

**complete dataframe:**

| comment | sentiment |
| --- | --- |
| fast running | 0.9 |
| heavily raining | 0.5 |
| in the house | 0.1 |
| coming in | 0.0 |
| rubbing it | -0.5 |

if I set a substring to filter my table:

```
substring = 'in'
comp = complete[complete.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains(substring, case=False).any(), axis=1)]
```

**output comp:**

| comment | sentiment |
| --- | --- |
| fast running | 0.9 |
| heavily raining | 0.5 |
| in the house | 0.1 |
| coming in | 0.0 |
| rubbing it | -0.5 |

It returns the same DF since all words do have "in" as a substring.

**My desired output:**

| comment | sentiment |
| --- | --- |
| in the house | 0.1 |
| coming in | 0.0 |

Filter it only if the substring is found as a word, not as a substring.

¿How can this be done?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68382624/2956135 with `.str.contains`

Comment: I've tried Emma, with no success. @mozway answer is working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries (`\b`) in your pattern:

```
substring = 'in'
comp = complete[complete['comment'].str.contains(fr'\b{substring}\b', case=False)]
```

If you have many columns to check, aggregate after (this is much more efficient than `apply` with `axis=1`):

```
comp = complete[complete[list_of_cols].apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(fr'\b{substring}\b', case=False)).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: I believe this works, could you please tell me why '\b' does not affects if the substring is at the start of the string?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. In your case your only have `in` in the middle, so whether you use a starting or ending boundary only should give the same result.

Comment: For example: in the house (in at the start), coming in (in at the end), let me in this (in in the middle), in all of that cases \b{in}\b does work, I just want to now why?

Comment: Because `\b` matches a word boundary, i.e. the start/end of string or a non-word character

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which uses [`lookaround`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and `\w` means word character and `!\w` means no word character. See [`demonstration`](https://regex101.com/r/9HSpf8/1) to understand the logic.

```
sub = 'in'
df.loc[df.comment.str.contains(fr'(?<!\w){sub}(?!\w)'), :]
```

Output:

```
        comment  sentiment
2  in the house        0.1
3     coming in        0.0
```

Comment: It do work to, I've just test it! I mark mozway answer since he used the same lambda function I did.